# Set Button on Runtime

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am creating button on runtime like below...

```
    Button newCategoryButton = new Button(this);   
    newCategoryButton.setText(catName);
    newCategoryButton.setWidth(30);
    newCategoryButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bnt);     

    LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,     LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    ll.addView(newCategoryButton, lp);
```

But my problem is that it disappear when I back from that activity.

I want this permanent. And another problem is that how to set this button below on other button??

Comment: u did this code in the onCreate() method I believe!!

Comment: I am doing this on button click like Add Category..

Comment: I want that permanent... even after exit from application. Next time when restart my app it will be remain..

Comment: What you can do is add the button in xml and set its visibility to gone
and when you want that button just turn the visibility to Visible

this is an alternative and simple way to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 LinearLayout.LayoutParams  layoutParams;
 LinearLayout  ll;
   Button newCategoryButton=new Button(this)
   newCategoryButton.setText("Push Me");
 layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
 ll.addView(view, newCategoryButton);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should put this code in the onResume(), not on the onCreate() method ;-)

[image]

If you want to use the button under another one, you will need to use a LinearLayout with a vertical orientation!

```
LinearLayout myll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.yourLinearLayout);
myll.setLayoutParams(LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.WRAP_CONTENT);
myll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
myll.addView(view, Button1); 
myll.addView(view, Button2);
setContentView(myll)
```